# Width of dynamic functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const ref = React.createRef(); 
        const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);


      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setWidth((ref as any).current?.clientWidth);
        console.log(width);
      });
             


   

     <Dropdown
  setDropdownVisible={setDropdownVisible}
  title={<DropdownTitle />}
  ref={ref}
  className={`user-info flex max-w-full justify-center whitespace-nowrap border    pr-1  sm:py-0 ${ dropdownVisible ? ' min-w-[180px] rounded-t-[25px] p-2 sm:p-0' : 'rounded-full'}`}isPortal={true}>
```

I am tyring to access the width of an element , i have used portal. it either shows with as 0 or undefined.
how do i get the width of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown is a react component so you should use forwardRef and assign the ref to the element inside the Dropdown component.

```
const Dropdown = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Dropdown</div>);
```

Or I think if you wrapped the Dropdown in a div for example and used the ref with this div, It should work

```
<div ref={ref}>
    <Dropdown title={<>sdfds</>} />
  </div>
```

Comment: i tried the second one it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Dropdown is not a DOM element, you should put ref={ref} in a Dom element such as  or . In your sitiation, You can use forwardRef if  is coded by yourself.